# Material-UI CardText-- Make it Editable?

Tags: material-ui

I have a Material-UI card, following the [example card from the Material-UI docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card). What is the best method for making the CardText on it editable?

Comment: Calling it CardText is a bit mis-leading. It's more like the card body. In either case, you can fill it with editable components just as you would any other component that expects children (Paper, Dialog, etc.).

Comment: @VikR, What do you mean with CardText exactly?

Answer (score -1):

Use  inside the card and with the initial text as defaultValue then customize it to look like a text and not a text field.